# How to pass event and $ as parameter in jQuery (noconflict mode enabled in wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

The code in question is in here :

https://github.com/louisremi/WordPress-Sortable-Posts/blob/master/script.js

This does not work in latest wordpress (`$` is not defined), so I'm passing `$` in every function.
This function is creating a lot of headache :

```
jQuery(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
```

I would like to use `$` as parameter too :

```
jQuery(document).on('mousemove', function(e , $ ) {
```

But its throwing error : either `e` / `$` not defined.
Any way to get past this?

Comment: what do you want to do with `$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your code in IIFE with jQuery as a parameter

```
(function($){
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    ....
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a wrapper:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e , $ ) {

    });
})(jQuery);
```

The "wrapper method" is discussed briefly [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).